# XSLT: preserve html tags in node value and apply templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<sectiondiv>
    <p>
        <ph linebreak="true">
            Lorem<br/>&#160;&#160;Ipsum<br/>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </ph>
    </p>
    <p>
        <ph image-relation="test" linebreak="true“>
            Lorem<br/><br/>Ipsum:<br/><br/>testsentence<br/><myref kind="Variable" type="PlainText">1 684 463 394</myref ><br/><br/>
        </ph>
    </p>
</sectiondiv>
```

I want to transform this XML and preserve the HTML tags in the several nodes.
In addition I want to apply additional templates on the values, e.g. the myref tag has its own template.

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

"Preservation" of elements can be achieved with [identity transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985056/xslt-identity-transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to perform additional transformations for *some* tags, then put those templates before the identity transformation template, as such:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="myref">
    <strong>myref encountered!</strong>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's not working for me. I want to apply additional templates to the value of the <ph> elements.

Comment: @Drag0ndust: You didn't say that in your question. In order to change `<ph>` elements you can do something similar to what I've done with the `myref` template. But best: Why not show the code that you have so far?

Comment: I can't show you my transformation because of nda issues. But you can see the second <ph>: all the html tags in the value have to be preserved and on myref a template has to be applied